# Fetch AWS Cognito Identity ID from Erlang code

Tags: amazon-web-services, erlang, ejabberd, amazon-cognito

Can anyone suggest please how to call AWS Cognito APIs from an Erlang application (am currently using ejabberd)?

I'd like to get the identityID and token from Cognito using GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity, but AWS apparently does not have a published Erlang SDK. The only available SDK erlcloud does not have a Cognito interface, so would appreciate if someone can throw some light on how to go about achieving that...

Or would I rather make my Erlang code call a Javascript that in turn calls the AWS API? If so, is erlang_js the way to go...?

Comment: I can't give an absolute answer as I know very little about Erlang, but you'd be doing less re-inventing of the wheel if you call JS. Cognito has wrappers in some of their SDKs (JS, iOS, and Android) that manage lots of little things for you, which could make your life a bit easier.

Comment: @JeffBailey Hmmm... thanks Jeff... so essentially, if I infer your recommendation correctly, you're saying that instead of having the Erlang server make the Cognito authentication directly, I should actually have the iOS app make a separate call to, say a Node.js API, that then calls the Cognito method?

Comment: Something like that could work well. You're welcome to try to use a different SDK directly, but I do think your life will be easier if you use one of those SDKs instead. The client side SDKs mentioned above should help a lot.

Comment: Thanks @JeffBailey ... would agree with you ...